# Make application With timers etc.?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I need to make an application as followed.

A query needs to be executed 10 times a second to check in the database (Ms SQL 2005) if the value of the field is 1 or 0. if its 1 then the appication needs to start Windows Media Player (Fullscreen) and run a video. 
The application needs to sleep during the video and when the video is finished the application needs to awake and close Windows Media Player and open Internet Explorer(fullscreen) and show a website.

I have no idea how to make this im not that experienced with Delphi.

Comment: It would probably be easier to embed the video on your form instead of launching and waiting for Media Player to exit.

Comment: @Andreas or maybe even simpler to embed the video itself into a web page

Comment: `I need to make an application as followed...` You can't seriously expect us to be your project managers. You can certainly receive some guidelines, even more so since nearly every part of your future application promises some good and interesting questions, more or less. But keep in mind that the main effort to be put into putting everything together is going to be yours. And for a good start, please follow David Heffernan's advice and split your question into several more specific and to the point ones.

Comment: Voted to close. overly broad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop a [`TTimer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TTimer) onto a Delphi form.  Set the timer's interval property to 100 (measured in milli-seconds).  Assign an event handler for the `OnTimer` event that checks your database.  Set the `Enabled` property to `False`.

When you want the timer to start firing events set `Enabled` to True. When you want it disabled, set `Enabled` back to `False`.

One thing to be careful of is if your timer event handler takes more time to run than the timer interval. If that happens then there will be no pause in between invocations of the handler.  This won't do any terrible harm, but it may result in your app consuming 100% CPU.  A defensive technique is to set the timer's Enabled property to False at the beginning of your event handler, and then back to True just before you exit the handler.

---

Re-reading your question, it occurs to me that perhaps you are asking how to do the database access, starting Media Player, sleeping during the video, waiting for it finish, opening IE etc.

You can't ask how to do all of that in one question (please see the FAQ for a description of what is a valid question on Stack Overflow).  If you really want answers to all of that then we'll just close the question as being too broad.

My answer above gives you some orientation for the timer part of your question.

Comment: Bit of a confusion, disabling timer in the handler will prevent re-entrancy not message accumulation. Timer messages do not accumulate anyway (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311246/is-the-ttimer-ontimer-event-handler-reentrant/3311416#3311416)). But if the work takes more than the interval the application will of course use high CPU.

Comment: @sertac my terminology was probably poor. Reentrancy is not the issue. Build up is not the issue. High CPU is the issue I am trying to pinpoint.

Comment: @David - Ok then! :) A better defense for that would be to give it a longer interval I guess.. :)

Comment: @sertac only works if you can predict how long the handler will take!

Comment: @David - My point was, disabling the timer in the handler will not prevent high CPU usage.. Can't you at least take out *"message queue will become saturated with timer messages*"?

Comment: @Sertac Disabling the timer in the handler does prevent high CPU usage.

Comment: @David - I don't see why?..   Set an interval of 50ms, handler code: `for i := 0 to 1000000000 do Tag := i;` I don't see any CPU usage difference if I surround it between disable/enable or not.. But I see it is difficult to discuss this in comments...  Regardless, 'message saturation' is simply wrong.

Comment: @Sertac Yes, I changed that already. You are quite correct on that score.

Comment: @David, Oops, I've missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require a delphi form application you could do this with a server-side web page (php, asp.net, jsp whatever's your favorite).

- Inital page load (server side) would check your database (1 or 0)?
- Client side page would refresh every n sec.
- ... or play video and redirect to website
- Website redirects to Inital page after n sec.

If you can't control the website you need to display you could call it inside a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling that record continuosly, I'd use a trigger to tell my application when the values has changed - of course if you can add such a trigger to the database.

If you can't add a trigger, I'd use a separate thread to check for the field change (use a proper query prepared with bind variables to avoid statement reparsing overhead). The thread can be put to sleep while the application plays the video - check what's the best way to run Media Player (embedded or not), because you need to know when it has finished playing, and I do not know if it is easy to obtain that information if Media Player is run as an external application using ShellExecute or CreateProcess, while it is easy enough to run an external application and wait for it to terminate.

Opening Explorer is just a matter of calling ShellExecute (or CreateProcess) with the right parameters.